# Two dimentional array value to another signal in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have created a two dimensional array.

```
type dataout is array (12 downto 0, 12 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal a : dataout;
```

The values are passing through the array and operation like addition and subtraction are also performing but i am not getting the way to pass this value of array to pass through another signal or output port.

Suggest me how to pass these values to another array, signal and output port.

Comment: You need to explain what *specific* problem or error message you are seeing. If you include some code as well, you are more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: architecture behave of test_1 is
type dataout is array (NO_OF_ROWS-1 downto 0, NO_OF_COLS-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal a : dataout;
signal b : dataout;

Comment: the values from input port are passing in array a(i,j) and being calculated in array a(i,j) like a(i,j)<=pdata_in + a(i,j). But these values from array a(i,j) are not further transfer to other signal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an output port of type `dataout` and assign `a` to it.

To do this, the declaration of `dataout` must be in a package

```
package my_types is
   type dataout is array (12 downto 0, 12 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
end package my_types;
```

which you `use` both in this entity/arch and any outer layer that instantiates it.

```
use work.my_types.all;
entity test is
    port(
       clock : in std_logic;
       a_out : out dataout
          );
end test;

architecture t of test is
   signal a : dataout;
begin
   a_out <= a;
end t;
```